# CXF webservice client throws IllegalArgumentException Algorithm suite "Basic128Exn256" is not registered

Tags: cxf, cxf-client

Looking for guidance on CXF webservice client

Cxf version: 3.2.1 
Web service client is a standalone java program. No web server configured.

I have wsdl file from the service provider which has

```
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
   <wsp:Policy>
      <sp:Basic128Exn256/>
   </wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
```

within `<wsp:Policy>` tag.

However, when starting cxf client, I get an exception as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Algorithm suite "Basic128Exn256" is not registered
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:161)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.importAndLoadData(Unknown Source)
    at temp.test.SoapServiceTest.main(SoapServiceTest.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Algorithm suite "Basic128Exn256" is not registered
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.custom.AlgorithmSuiteBuilder.build(AlgorithmSuiteBuilder.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.custom.AlgorithmSuiteBuilder.build(AlgorithmSuiteBuilder.java:37)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.build(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:174)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.wss4j.policy.builders.SymmetricBindingBuilder.build(SymmetricBindingBuilder.java:44)
    at org.apache.wss4j.policy.builders.SymmetricBindingBuilder.build(SymmetricBindingBuilder.java:34)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.build(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getAllOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:184)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getExactlyOneOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:180)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:215)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:174)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:124)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.reference.LocalServiceModelReferenceResolver.resolveReference(LocalServiceModelReferenceResolver.java:53)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.resolveLocal(Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.java:292)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.resolveReference(Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.getElementPolicy(Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.getElementPolicy(Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.java:168)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.getElementPolicy(Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.java:161)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.getEffectivePolicy(Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.java:98)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getAggregatedEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.initializePolicy(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:152)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.initialize(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:140)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.createEndpointPolicyInfo(PolicyEngineImpl.java:604)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:316)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getClientEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:303)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyDataEngineImpl.getClientEndpointPolicy(PolicyDataEngineImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.updateClientPolicy(HTTPConduit.java:325)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.updateClientPolicy(HTTPConduit.java:345)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.getClient(HTTPConduit.java:879)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.configureConduitFromEndpointInfo(HTTPConduit.java:367)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.finalizeConfig(HTTPConduit.java:447)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getConduit(HTTPTransportFactory.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(SoapTransportFactory.java:226)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(SoapTransportFactory.java:233)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.createConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.getSelectedConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:108)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.UpfrontConduitSelector.prepare(UpfrontConduitSelector.java:63)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.prepareConduitSelector(ClientImpl.java:853)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:511)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139)
```

Same wsdl, when I write a pure jax-ws client without cxf, it works. 
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

"Basic128Exn256" is not a standard algorithm suite that is defined in the specs. If you want to support it in CXF you'll have to write a custom AlgorithmSuite (e.g. http://coheigea.blogspot.ie/2011/09/specifying-custom-algorithmsuite.html)